# Is there a way to stack multiple 2x2 matrices in MATLAB into a multidimensional array in a simpler way (e.g. without using "cat" or "reshape")?

Tags: matlab, matrix, multidimensional-array, formatting, reformatting

I am receiving a text file with 1000 matrices of size 2x2 each day from someone, in the following format (only 3 matrices are shown here instead of 1000):

```
0.96875000 0.03125000 
0.03125000 0.96875000

0.96875000 0.01562500 
0.03125000 0.98437500

0.99218800 0.03125000 
0.00781250 0.96875000
```

I need to make a 2x2x1000 array in MATLAB. ***Ideally*** I could do something simple like:

```
[0.96875000 0.03125000 
0.03125000 0.96875000;

0.96875000 0.01562500 
0.03125000 0.98437500;

0.99218800 0.03125000 
0.00781250 0.96875000]
```

After reading the [MATLAB documentation on multidimensional arrays](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/multidimensional-arrays.html) and the [MATLAB documentation for the `cat` function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cat.html), I figured out that I could make the required array in the following way (the first argument of `cat` is `3` because I'm concatenating the 2x2 matrices along the 3rd dimension):

```
cat(3,...
[0.96875000 0.03125000 
0.03125000 0.96875000],...
[0.96875000 0.01562500 
0.03125000 0.98437500],...
[0.99218800 0.03125000 
0.00781250 0.96875000])
```

But that does *not* work if I put spacing between the lines as in my "ideal" example above, and the need for all the commas and dots makes it a bit uglier in my opinion.

While writing this question, I have discovered that I can run my "ideal" example and then use `reshape`, which I prefer over my solution using the `cat` function. For this, I don't even need the semi-colons. However [Cris Luengo correctly pointed out in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63404311/is-there-a-way-to-stack-multiple-2x2-matrices-in-matlab-into-a-multidimensional#comment112115215_63404311) that `reshape` is not enough and `permute` is also needed, and then [Luis Mendo pointed out in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/50206049#50206049) that the solution is not so simple:

```
permute(reshape(ideal.',2,2,[]),[2 1 3])
```

[Andras Deak has done](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/50206194#50206194) what we [thought was impossible](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/50206099#50206099), which is to remove the transpose, but the solution is still quite complicated, and was not easy to engineer:

```
permute(reshape(ideal,2,[],2),[1 3 2])
```

Ideally one would not need to use `cat` or `reshape` to make a 3D array, when the original data is already so nicely formatted in what the human eye can already see is a 3D array of several 2x2 matrices.

**Is there a simpler way to build the 3D array in MATLAB using the data in the format I have?**

So far I have done the following on my own:

- Searched online and found the above two MATLAB documentation articles which lead me to the above solution using `cat`
- Came up with the above solution using `reshape` while writing this question, then it got improved by Cris and Luis in the comments and chat .
- Also: I tried saving the data in a .txt file and clicked `import` in MATLAB, knowing that the import GUI gives some options for how the data is to be organized in the resulting MATLAB array, but there did not seem to be any option to make this a 3D array.

Comment: I think you will have to import it as a 2D array and then use `reshape` and `permute` to get it to where you need to be. Only `reshape` would create a 2x1000x2 array, if you initially read it in as a 2000x2 array.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I just noticed that, the the `reshape` solution is even less elegant than I thought. Ideally when the data is already formatted in a way so close to what I want, it would not require so much to build the 3D array!

Comment: MATLAB doesn't have a syntax for 3D arrays, `cat` and `reshape` are the simplest ways to make a 3D array. On the positive side, you don't need to modify your text file at all, you can just put `data=[` at the top, and `];` at the bottom.

Comment: It's possible that someone had data in a similar format, and wrote a function to read it as a 3D array, and posted it on the File Exchange. As you said, it seems trivial to parse the text file and interpret it as a 3D array. You just need to have the code to do so because MATLAB doesn't do that natively AFAIK.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I understand that I just have to put data=[ at the top and ] at the bottom. It does seem strange that MATLAB wouldn't have a native way to do this though, for example: double semi-colon between each matrix "page".

Comment: Is this a question about "how can I make this look nicer"? If so, I doubt that writing 1000 2x2 matrices will hardly ever produce nice code ;) Where do those matrices come from? Are you reading them in iteratively? Than you can do slicing `Mat3D = NaN(2,2,1000)` + looping `Mat3D(:,:,i) = magic(2)`

Comment: How do you read the text file in the first place? Do you read it with a Matlab function or do you open the text file and place your characters `[`, `]` manually ?

Comment: @Hoki I deliberately refrained from getting specific about that because I am open to any solution more elegant than what I currently have. Currently I place the [ ] manually because it's easy, and I mentioned `import` which is not so nice either but considering that it's looking like there's no way to read in 3D arrays "natively": maybe `load('file.txt')` where file.txt is the first code block in my question, followed by `permute(reshape(ideal.', 2, 2, []), [2 1 3])` is the best way?

Comment: Yes, loading the file without having to modify it by hand first is the best way. Then to reorganise it into the shape you're after, I don't think you can find shorter (or more native) code. The `permute(reshape(...),...)` method is probably the fastest way as well.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed there is no "direct" way to import this text as a 3D matrix. This is the easiest way I can come up with:

1. Save the input as a .txt file
2. Use the import tool (Import Data button in the Variable toolbar) to import the data as a Mx2 matrix. Choose "Numeric Matrix" as "Output Type". And you can "exclude rows with" "blank cells" to avoid the empty rows.
3. Besides reshape() and permute(), using cell array to format it as below might be more intuitive and less error prone to someones.

```
    % The number of 2x2 matrices
    N = size(m,1)/2;
    % Split each 2x2 matrix into a cell
    c = mat2cell(m, 2*ones(1,N), 1);
    % Concatenate along the 3rd dimension
    output3DMatrix = cat(3, c{:});
```

Comment: Thanks. Easiest so far is: `load('file.txt'); permute(reshape(file.', 2, 2, []), [2 1 3])`